# How do you extract words in a list in python

Tags: python, list

So Im teaching myself how to program. So far I am going nowhere.

I have a code that from a line in a textfile, I put each word of that line in a list. Let's say the list is `info =[john,guard,single]`. I have successfully loaded the words into the list but have some problems with my next task.
i want to get each word and use it in a sentence
all i have done so far is

```
for word in info:
    print "My name is ",word[1]
    print "My job is " ,word[2]
    print "I am ",word[3]
```

but all i get is 
   My name is o
   My job is h
   I am n
can someone please help me?

ok so here's the code:

```
def loginfo(self):
    infolist = []
    with open('user.txt') as f:
        f = f.readlines()
        for line in f:
            if str(self.neim.get()) in line:
               if str(self.posse.get()) in line:
                  for word in line.split():
                      infolist.append(word)

    for word in infolist:
        print word[]
```

Comment: It looks like you are accessing the strings individually instead of the list. Can post your code please?

Comment: What is `infolist`? Is it a single dimensional list with 'name', 'job' and 'status' being repeated? Or is it a 2D List?

Comment: Well, I planned that the infolist be empty first. Then the code will search the textfile for a specific word that i will input. If a line contains that word then the each word of the line goes into the infolist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something along these lines:

```
li=['My name is {}', "My job is {}", "I am {}"]
info=['john','guard','single']

for x, y in zip(li, info):
    print x.format(y)
```

Prints:

```
My name is john
My job is guard
I am single
```

Or, just use a single template:

```
print 'My name is {}\nMy job is {}\nI am {}'.format(*info)
```

Comment: thank you! Will this still work if i pass it as a parameter in a function? Like login(*infolist)

Comment: Well, yes, depending on how the function is written. This: `f1(1,2,3)` is the same as `f2(*[1,2,3])` but not the same as `f3([1,2,3])`. `f3` has 1 argument -- a list with 3 elements; `f1` has 3 arguments and `f2` has a list that is expanded into 3 arguments. See Python docs on [functions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) and [what does the * do](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/298607)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that `for` loop. You can simply:

```
print "My name is ",info[0]
print "My job is " ,info[1]
print "I am ",info[2]
```

In your loop you iterating over the list and assigning each string inside it to the variable `word`. you were then accessing the word with the index method `[]`. Which is why you were getting individual letters instead of words. Also computers start counting at 0 not 1 so the indexes go:

```
[0,1,2,3]
```

So when you use a for loop like this:

```
for word in info:
    print(word[0])
```

What happens is:

- The first element in the list is accessed which in your case is the
  string `John`
- Next you call the index method on word `word[0]`
- That will access and return the character in the 0th index which is
  the first character in the string
- It will do that whole set of instructions for every element in the list

Answer (score 0):

`for word in info:` is a *loop*. Its body (the indented part) will execute once for each element of `info`.

You could access `info` elements by index, as other answers suggest. You can also *unpack* the list into reasonably-named variables:

```
name, job, marital_status = info # the unpacking: 3 variables for 3 list items
print "My name is", name, "my job is", job, "I am", marital_status
```

The loop comes in handy when you have a list of people to process:

```
people = [  # a list of lists
  ["Joe", "painter", "single"],
  ["Jane", "writer", "divorced"],
  ["Mario", "plumber", "married"]
]

for person_info in people:
  print "Name:", person_info[0], "job:", person_info[1], "is", person_info[2]
```

It is idiomatic to unpack nested items right in the loop:

```
for name, job, marital_status in people:
  print "Person named", name, "works as a", job, "and is", marital_status
```